# How to enter a switch statement on button pressed

Tags: php, sql

I am building a game for a uni assignment where the user answers yes or no to computer question and the computer will guess that animal. It uses a self referencing database for the backend and is being coded in php.

I thought the best way to to this would be to create a variable called $currentnode to keep track of where the game was in terms of the current question being asked, and use that to make a decision of the next question.

I have tried to use a switch statement on this which should be triggered by the the yes or no button being pressed.The switch should take the currentnode and match it with a case and update the where clause and run the query to select the correct question from the database. 
I have started by using Isset on the yes button and building a switch for all yes answers, but I cannot get the switch statement to be trigger when the yes button is pressed.

My aim is for every button press of yes or no, a switch statement should be entered, the currrentnode matched an the corresponding where clause added to the query and ran.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
$query = "SELECT `message`, `nodeID` FROM `creature`";//basic query that will be used     at all times
$where = "";//empty where clause, will be altered 
$currentnode;//used to store current state



//function created to be re used after an answer is given
function output($query,$where,$dbconn){
$result = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query.$where);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 echo "{$row['message']}
    {$row['nodeID']}<br>";}


 echo '<form action="play.php" method="GET">
<input type="submit" name="yes" value="yes">
<input type="submit" name="no" value="no">
<input type = "submit" name = "restart" value = "restart game">
</form>';}

?>

<form action="play.php" method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="start" value="Start Game">
</form>

<?php
$currentnode = '0';
if ( isset( $_POST['start'] ))
{ 
$currentnode = 1;
$where = "WHERE `nodeID` = '1'";
output($query,$where,$dbconn);
echo 'current node is '; echo $currentnode;
} 

if (isset ($_GET['yes'])){

switch ($currentnode){

case 1: $where = "WHERE `nodeID` = '2'"; output($query,$where,$dbconn);
break;

case 2: $where = "WHERE `nodeID = '3'"; output($query,$where,$dbconn);
break;
}
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Better do that as an interactive commandline application where the user enters data and the program wait's until the user presses ENTER. Then you can continue in your code. http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-command/

Comment: Not sure how can change the question to narrow it down?

Comment: Perhaps by painting a picture. I assume what you want to ask about is more a structural or design question. You're perhaps confrontent with state in your program flow while with PHP/HTTP it's more a state-less way of doing things. Eg. pass `$currentnode` as parameter into your script as well.

Comment: My question is how to get the switch statement to do anything when I place it inside the if block that tests if the button is pressed. At the moment, when the yes button is pressed, nothing happens.

Comment: You just place it into that block. Maybe the PHP manual page for if helps? http://php.net/if

Comment: Yes I have place the switch statement inside the if (isset) block, when I press the button it skips to the default of the switch statement

Comment: The the switch statement works, see http://php.net/switch to understand why the default case is triggered.